# Relating the pairwise determinants of $n$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A similar question may have already been answered somewhere, but I have not been able to find it.

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be elements of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, with $v_i=\begin{pmatrix} a_i \\ b_i \end{pmatrix}$ for all $i$. For all $i<j$, define $n_{ij}:=\operatorname{det}(v_i,v_j)=a_ib_j-a_jb_i$. Which $\binom{n}{2}$-tuples of integers can be equal to $\{n_{ij}\}_{i<j}$ for some collection of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$?

*Edit*: the question is not clear. What I mean is: given $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{Z}^2$, set $N(v_1,\dots,v_n):=\{n_{ij}\}_{i<j}$, in the same notations as before. For which $\binom{n}{2}$-tuples of integers $S$ there exist $w_1,\dots,w_n \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $N(w_1,\dots,w_n)=S$?

As Jean Marie points out, this is equivalent to the following question. Which $n \times n$ skew symmetric, integer matrices $N$ of rank two can be written as $N=AB^T-BA^T$, for column vectors $A,B \in \mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: It might be simpler to regard $n_{ij}$ as an antisymmetric matrix and remove the requirement that $i<j$.

Answer (score 2):

As the text of your question has been modified, my previous answer (A1) has become obsolete. But I just added an Edit (A2), which is only a very partial solution.

- **Here was my previous answer (A1) :**

Your issue can be re-written in the following way: if a $n \times n$ matrix $N$ can be written in the form $AB^T-BA^T$ (therefore is a rank-2 skew symmetric matrix), where $A,B$ are $n \times 1$ column vectors, can other solutions $N=A'B'^T-B'A'^T$ exist ?

The answer is yes in the case of real coefficients : just take

$$A'=uA, \ \ B'=vB \ \ \text{with} \ \ uv=1$$

(which amounts to a shrinkage on the $a_i$ and an extension of the $b_j$ (or the contrary).

In the integer case, in order to have a non trivial solution (set apart solution $u=v=-1$), it is necessary that the $a_i$ or the $b_i$ have a GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) $>1$.

**Edit : (A2) : a "pseudo-answer" :**

As the rank of your matrix $N$ is two and that the non-zero *eigenvalues* of an antisymmetric matrix are known to come in conjugate pairs, $\pm ia$, the *singular values* of $N$ are :

$$-a^2,-a^2,0,0...$$

Therefore, the SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) of $N$ can be written :

$$N=-a^2 UV^T -a^2U'V'^T\tag{1}$$

Where $U,U'$ are the left (resp. $V,V'$ the right) singular vectors of $N$.

(1) can be written, by incorporating the $a^2$ factors into vectors :

$$N=UV^T-U'V'^T$$

But I am unable at present to establish that necessarily, $U'=V$ and $V'=U$, not to speak of the possibility that their entries can be integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have phrased my question better. What I meant, in your notation, is the following: how can you characterize all skew symmetric, integer matrices $N$ of rank two admitting a decomposition of the form $N=AB^T-BA^T$?
I will edit the question to explain better what I meant.

Comment: This is a nice post, but 1) as the OP already mentioned, the question was a bit different, and 2) "I don't think a solution exists" is hardly an answer, and should probably be a comment.

Comment: @lisyarus 1) The question has been slightly modified since I wrote this answer 2)  You are right : I erase this last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a sketch of a proof:

The problem ( and its generalization) consists of two parts:

1. What can be said about the $k\times k$ minors of $k \times n$ minors of a matrix with coefficient in some field?

The answer is given by the [Plucker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding)

---

2. Let $R$ be a domain, $k$ its field of fractions. Assume that we have a $k\times n$ matrix with elements in $k$ such that all its $k\times k$ minors are in $R$.  Does there exist another $k\times n$ matrix with elements in $R$ with the same $k\times k$ minors?

The answer is Yes if $R$ is a PID. For this, use the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

---

This part seems tricky so I am adding more details. The statement is this: given a matrix $M$ of size $k \times n$ with rational entries and all of the $k\times k$ minors integers, there exists a matrix $M'$ of size $k\times n$, with integer entries, and same corresponding $k\times k$ minors.

Indeed, consider the Smith normal form of $M$

$$M = S \cdot D \cdot T$$

where $S \in SL(k, \mathbb{Z})$, $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1, \ldots, d_k)$, and $T \in SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$, with $\det D = d_1 \cdots d_k$ equals the $\operatorname{gcd}$ of all the $k\times k$ minors of $M$, so integer. ( the Smith normal form works for matrices $M$ with rational entries, just bring all to a common denominator).  Now consider the matrix $M' = S\cdot D'\cdot T$, where $D' = \operatorname{diag}(1, 1, \ldots, 1, d_1\cdots d_k)$.  Note that the only change is from $D$ to $D'$ ( the matrices $D$, $D'$  are not exactly diagonal, since they are size $k\times n$). The $k\times k$ minors of $D$ equalt the corresponding $k\times k$ minors of $D'$. Moreover, $D'$ has integer entries ( obviously, since $d_1\cdot d_k$ is integer). We conclude that $M'$ has integer entries and the same $k\times $ minors ( from Cauchy-Binet)  as $M$.

---

Examples:

- Q: what can be said about the $2\times 2$ minors of a $2\times 3$ matrix with integer coefficients? A: They are integers.
- Q: what can be said about the $2\times 2$ minors $m_{ij}$, $1\le i< j \le 4$, of a $2\times 4$ matrix with integer coefficients? A: $m_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m_{12}m_{34} -m_{13}m_{24}+m_{14}m_{23} = 0$.
- Q: what can be said about the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ minors of a $(n-1)\times n$ matrix with integer coefficients? A: They are integers.

---

Why do we have the Plucker relations ( the necessity)?  If we have $k+1$ column vectors of size $k$ then among them there is a generic linear dependence given by the Cramer rule. For instance, for $4$ column vectors of size $3$ we have

$$(v_1 v_2 v_3) v_4 = ( v_4, v_2, v_3)v_1 + (v_1, v_4, v_3) v_2 + (v_1 v_2 v_4) v_3$$

Now if these vectors $v_i$ are columns of some $3\times n$ matrix, consider completing the linear relation above to something involving product of determinants, as follows

$$(v_1, v_2, v_3)(v_4 v_k v_l) - (v_4 v_2v_3) (v_1, v_k, v_l) - (v_2, v_4 v_3)(v_2 v_k v_l) - ( v_1 v_2 v_4) (v_3 v_k v_l)$$

so we got one of the (many) Plucker relations. ( Not all of them are independent)

The converse ( that given the equality we can find $n$ columns of size $k$ satisfying $a_{ijk} = (v_i v_jv_k)$ is a bit more involved.